# HTML - Break line in a pre tag

Tags: jquery, newline, line-breaks

I am trying to copy (with jQuery and JS) text written in a textarea to a pre tag.
However, I cannot introduce as many line breaks as I want.  For instance, if I press Enter once, it works and I create a line break, but if I press Enter more than once I cannot get more than one line break. Do you know why this happens, or how I can fix it?

The code goes pretty much like this:

```
<textarea id="area" rows="5" cols="30"> </textarea> 
<pre id="area2" > </pre> <br/>

<script>
newText = $( '#area' ).val();
$( '#pre' ).text( newText); 
</script>`
```

The id of the textarea is #area and the id of the pre tag is #pre

Comment: i m trying to copy it to a PRE tag ..

Comment: Hi - you can use the 'edit' button to edit extra detail into the question instead of adding it as a comment.

Comment: could you be more specific - as in include precisely what you want to have happen in an example and include the code and what you observe?

Comment: Working just fine on IE, Chrome and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/tQn4h/ just type something, put as much Enters as you like click Copy and see the new lines are preserved.

Comment: If by "working fine" you mean "not working at all" then I agree. Perhaps it is a browser issue. When I type "a \n\n\n b" I see "a (multiple spaces) b" in the fiddle.

Comment: @antonis and Dwb: can your try alerting `newText.length` with the values `abc\n`, `abc\n\n` and `abc\n\ncba`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with IE7. It doesn't display more that one newline within a pre tag.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing

```
$( '#pre' ).html( newText);
```

instead? It could be that the `.text` strips out the `\n`'s

If this doesn't work, I've found some answer to a similar questions here on Stack Overflow,
which might work for you. However it's kind of a pain since you've got to write a rather big function that detects the newlines and replaces them:

```
    //Based off <textarea id="text" cols="50" rows="5" style="overflow: scroll">This is 
a test sentence, with no newline characters in it, but with an automatically wrapped sentence that spans three lines.</textarea>
    var words = $("#text").val().split(" ");
    var cols = $("#text").attr("cols");
    var text = "";
    var lineLength = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var word = words[i];
        if ((lineLength + word.length + 1) > cols) {
            text += "\n";
            lineLength = 0;
        } else if (lineLength > 0) {
            text += " ";
            lineLength++;
        }
        text += word;
        lineLength += word.length;
    }
    $( '#pre' ).text(text);
    //Alerts:
    //This is a test sentence, with no newline
    //characters in it, but with an automatically
    //wrapped sentence that spans three lines.
```